# Why can't I run includes on values of an object in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

Why do I get typescript errors on this?

```
const myObj = {
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: "3"
} as const;

const hasFour = Object.values(myObj).includes("4");
// Argument of type '"4"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"1" | "2" | "3"'.ts(2345)
```

I would expect typescript to know that the result is an array of strings. Why do I need to cast the `Object.values` to `string[]` first? Why isn't this inferred?

Comment: Can see this has been closed, but just in case... I think the type inference is broken by your 'as const;'. Remove that and the code should be compilable (it is in my IDE). If you wanted a cleaner type declaration, something like Record<string, string> may be more suitable.

Comment: You can check [my article](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns#includes) about this issue